# I want to know which CMS or theme is used for this E-Commerce..?

Tags: wordpress, magento, canvas, woocommerce, e-commerce

Anyone can help me out. I want to know that which CMS is this for website https://www.pipabella.com/  and specially how can i implement this https://www.pipabella.com/pb-personalized-jewelry?prodType=0  customization option for my woo commerce E-Commerce. your help will be appreciable thanks in advance .!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This browser extension maybe helps: [Wappalyzer](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/), or [whatcms.org](https://whatcms.org/)

Though the most common thing is to use cms for e-commerce, there can be personalized sites without that.

Comment: Actually i want to this kind of customization functionality and How can i go for it.? have a look visit this link and let me know thanks.!!  https://www.pipabella.com/pb-personalized-jewelry?utm-source=nav

Answer (score 1):

That site uses Magento.  I like to use https://builtwith.com/ to see what a site is built with (hence the name).  There is no need to add an extension to your browser, though you can if you like.  :)

As for the customization option, I'm not certain what you mean.  Magento (or any of the popular e-commerce CMS options) has many extensions that will help to customize products.

Comment: Actually i want to this kind of customization functionality and How can i go for it.? have a look visit this link and let me know thanks.!!  https://www.pipabella.com/pb-personalized-jewelry?utm-source=nav

Comment: Do you mean the functionality that takes a user's input (text) and puts it into the images?  That appears to be custom built functionality to me.  It doesn't seem to be an extension.  I looked at the source code, and there are thousands of lines of custom JavaScript/jQuery.  I don't know if there is an extension that does this without a lot of custom development.